# List comprehension with rsplit, invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `variables` of strings of the form `x.y`. I want to do a list comprehension which splits the string after `as`, that is leaves the part `y` and part `{aggr}({var})` at the beginning is left untouched

```
[f'{aggr}({var}) as {var.rsplit('.',1)[1]}_{aggr}' for var in variables]
```

where `aggr` is a string I input in a function. This gives me invalid syntax error. When I don't split i.e.:

```
[f'{aggr}({var}) as {var}_{aggr}' for var in variables]
```

it works. How do I fix it?

Comment: use `"` instead of `'` in `rsplit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop breaking your string.

```
f'{aggr}({var}) as {var.rsplit(".",1)[1]}_{aggr}'
```